# Indian snake ID

Tags: species-identification, snake

I saw this snake being attacked on the ground by a dog and it escaped up a tree with amazing rapidity. Can anyone help with the ID?[image] It was maybe nearly a metre long. Seen in Rajasthan.

Comment: Quite hard to ID without being able to see the pattern on the dorsal side.